# Install Locally Developed Python Module

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-module

I am currently in the process of developing a module that I am using as a library to be imported in another project. I need a sane way that I can install this module in the python site packages in such a way that I don't need to reinstall it everytime I make changes to it. Currently, I am using `sudo pip install --force-reinstall {BASE_FOLDER_FOR_MODULE}`, but need to re run this command everytime I make any changes to the module code.

The little bit of info I've been able to find on the subject seems to indicate that while I can symlink the base folder for the module in the site-packages folder for my other project, that this may not necessarily be a good way to do it. Is symlinking the folder bad, and if so why? Is there an alternate (better) option?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If the library is still under active development then consider adding it to environment variable [`PYTHONPATH`](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH). Directories in `PYTHONPATH` are appended to `sys.path` and are searched last when trying to find a module. Using `PYTHONPATH` means you only have to make minimal changes (set it in a config file source file or `.bashrc` file) for things to work. Once the library is finalised you can install it to the site-packages directory and remove it from `PYTHONPATH`.

Comment: I'm trying to do this, and while I see my folder in list when I print out sys.path, I can't import the module.

My folder structure is `base_folder/src/folder1/all my code lives here`. The setup.py file is located in the base folder.

I've tried making `PYTHONPATH` to be both the base folder and `folder1` in this example, and still can't load the module by its name'

Comment: Are you exporting `PYTHONPATH`? An environment variable is only visible to the current process unless it is exported. eg `export PYTHONPATH=blah` (for bash).

Comment: I added an export statement to my bash profile and made sure to source the profile before trying it

Comment: The `.bash_profile` is only executed once, at login. `.bashrc` is executed every time you open a new terminal. You will need to logout and login again for the changes in `.bash_profile` to take effect. Try setting `PYTHONPATH` on the command line and then running `python -m my_module` first though.